rigid insulation with vapour barrier out
Is there an issue with having rigid foam board with vapour barrier (isofoil) installed on outside wall?

drywall
vapour barrier ( plastic )
batts between studs
-> rigid foam board with vapour barrier (isofoil) <-
fiber board
house wrap

I would like to know if i need to remove the wrap, fiber board then pull off the vapor barrier from rigid board to prevent humidity being accumulated between 2 vapour barriers, then reinstall fiber board and house wrap.

Location matters which end the vapour barrier goes, but usually only one vapour barrier should be used.
